# What type of error should this be?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

Take this stub of code as an example:

```
class Wizard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            steps: this.props.children ? this.props.children.length : null
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.state.steps === null) {
            throw new Error(
                "The <Wizard /> component requires <Step /> components as children"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

What type of error should this be? I feel that there should be a *RequirementError*, but I've never heard of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe this is a PropType error, and is taken care of by React's PropTypes module. Here's a link to the document page:

[Typechecking with PropTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

PropTypes will run type checks on your component's props (aptly named) and throw info/error messages based on if they are missing required keys.

Code example:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // This must be an array of children or it will warn.
    const children = this.props.children;
    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element).isRequired
};
```

Edit: Out of context of React, I think the type of error would be a **ChildType** Error

Comment: I cited you the edit to my question. I'm really interested in a library / framework agnostic answer though.

Comment: Framework agnostically I would consider it a ChildType error, that just feels the most appropriate since Children is simply an array of Child objects and ChildrenType is 3 characters longer :(. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok so that would be a custom error type. I'm not trying to be a pain, but I'm looking for a higher level answer. I think I was too specific in my example, that is my fault.

Comment: Actually I will accept your answer, because I didn't ask my question properly and you provided a good answer.